# Minimum video card to support 1440x900

Tags: graphics-card, resolution

I'm wondering if a 8mb video card support 1440x900? If not, what is the minimum video card to support 1440x900?

Comment: I know there is a chart somewhere. Once I had a 1mb video card and I was looking for the max resolution on that and found a chart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calculation:

width * height * 4 = ...

4 because we want 32bit color, 32bit = 4bytes

In your case: **1440 * 900 * 4 = 5 184 000 ~ 5MB ;)**

The problem might be with an old card, that the (old) driver doesn't support this,
 unless you're lucky, and the manufacturer has even today still driver support for such an old graphics card.

Comment: I didn't even think about the driver issue.

Comment: 1440x900 was an uncommon resolution for older video cards, so I have run into the driver issue with older nVidia/ATI cards (for example, in a Toshiba M200 tablet PC {connected to external monitor})